# Git log --pretty=format with lines added and removed?

Tags: git, git-log

I'd like to have a flag like:

```bash
git log --pretty="format: %added %removed %cd"
```

As far as I can see those flags are not available in `format:<string>`.

I've read [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and it doesn't seem to exist, but it seems like such an obvious thing to include that I'm wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: Doesn't `git log --stat` already do that?

Comment: But it isn't used as part of --pretty=format:<string>.  I'd like to be able to get the stat information on one line.

Comment: I think you should use `--shortstat` with perl or other tools.

Comment: You might be able to find some plumbing commands that you can use by grepping the Git repo documentation files. There's not format option to do what you want as far as I could tell. If this is something that you really want, you'll probably need to script it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to script it in order to display what you want, the closest native git command which display the lines added/removed per files in [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is:

```
git log --pretty=tformat: --numstat
```

With:

```
--numstat
```

> Similar to `--stat`, but shows number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly.
>   For binary files, outputs two - instead of saying `0 0`.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/KOGI/8700277) by [KOGI](https://github.com/KOGI) provides one example of such a script (not exactly what you are after, but you get the general idea)

```
git log --pretty=tformat: --numstat $@ "`git merge-base HEAD develop`..HEAD" | gawk '{ adds += $1 ; subs += $2 ; net += $1 - $2 ; gross += $1 + $2 ; commits += 1 } END { print "total commits\tadded loc\tremoved loc\tgross loc\tnet loc\n"; printf "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", commits, adds, subs, gross, net }' | column -s $'\t' -t
```